# Fix errors to upgrade old module for Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I've been using [this Modal module](https://github.com/kevcjones/ngx-simple-modal) for my Angular projects, however today, when upgrading to Angular 16, it stoped working with this error:

> 'SimpleModalModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
>
> simple-modal.module.d.ts(5, 54): This likely means that the library which declares SimpleModalModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

I forked the project and was trying to upgrade it, unfortunately I'm not that familiar with this level of editing on Angular, so I wasn't able to fix everything.

I could fix a couple of errors, specially related to `ReflectiveInjector deprecated` so I could get some progress and the project is building.

But when I import and try to use the component as it should, I'm getting this error now:

> Argument of type 'typeof ModalSigninComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<SimpleModalComponent<null, null>>'.
>
> Type 'ModalSigninComponent' is not assignable to type 'SimpleModalComponent<null, null>'.
>
> Types have separate declarations of a private property 'observer'.

Does anybody knows how to fix it to give a help on this? The repository seems to be dead and not maintained (last commit on dec 2021).